# converting a file into a pandas dataframe and access elements line by line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, os.walk

I'm trying to convert a given file into a pandas dataframe by using the pd.read_table() function. To access these files, I had to walk through a directory using the os.walk() function. I am then looping through that data frame to access the elements line by line and assigning 32 lines to an array, which I then assign to another bigger array. The problem is that when I print the list, it doesn't contain any elements. I think I'm going wrong in the data frame assignment statement but I'm not sure. The following is my code:

```
list_of_files = {}
for folder_name in activities:
    path = "C:\\Users\\Akarshkb\\Desktop\\cs361hw\\HMP_Dataset\\" + 
folder_name
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
        list_of_subunits = []
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith('.txt'): 
                list_of_files[filename] = os.sep.join([dirpath, filename])
                file = open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename), 'r')
                df = pd.read_table(file, sep='\s+', header = None)
                temp_array = []
                subunit_number = 32
                current_line_number = 0
                for line in df:
                    current_line_number = current_line_number + 1
                    temp_array.append(line)
                    if (current_line_number % subunit_number == 0):
                        list_of_subunits.append(temp_array)
                        temp_array.clear()
                file.close()
print ((list_of_subunits))
```

And the print statement is  just this : [[]]
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're redefining multiple things inside multiple `for` loops. Any container you want to use to collate data should be define outside of all the `for` loops. The only thing that persists is `list_of_files` which, unfortunately, is actually a dictionary, not a list.